# Why does Java client generation fail in Swagger Editor?

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

I just tried to create a Java for my JSON Swagger file within the Swagger Editor.
Unfortunately nothing happens if I try to generate the client.

In the Dev-Tools console of Chrome I can see an exception but I do not have any idea what went wrong and where to find more detailed information.

```
POST https://generator.swagger.io/api/gen/clients/java 500 (Request failed.)
index.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed.
    at index.js:1
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:62)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:296)
    at Generator.e.(/anonymous function) [as next] (https://editor.swagger.io/dist/swagger-editor-standalone-preset.js:1:104152)
    at step (asyncToGenerator.js:17)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:28
```

This is the JSON file used to generated the Java client:

```json
{
   "swagger":"2.0",
   "info":{
      "description":"REST API zur Anlage und Modifikation der Daten",
      "title":"Aktivierung / Aktualisierung / Deaktivierung der Daten",
      "version":"1"
   },
   "host":"myhost.server.local:8080",
   "basePath":"/metadata-webapp",
   "paths":{
      "/metadata/deactivate":{
         "put":{
            "summary":"Metadata Deactivation",
            "description":"",
            "operationId":"deactivate",
            "consumes":[
               "application/json"
            ],
            "produces":[
               "application/json"
            ],
            "parameters":[
               {
                  "in":"body",
                  "name":"body",
                  "description":"metadata key",
                  "required":true,
                  "schema":{
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/MetadataKey"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "responses":{
               "200":{
                  "description":"Request was processed"
               },
               "400":{
                  "description":"Bad Request, falls Validierung auf Request Objekt fehlschlägt"
               },
               "500":{
                  "description":"Interner Fehler"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "/metadata/individual":{
         "post":{
            "summary":"\tMetadata Insert Individual",
            "description":"",
            "operationId":"saveIndividual",
            "consumes":[
               "application/json"
            ],
            "produces":[
               "application/json"
            ],
            "parameters":[
               {
                  "in":"body",
                  "name":"body",
                  "description":"metadata",
                  "required":true,
                  "schema":{
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/MetadataIndividualInsert"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "responses":{
               "200":{
                  "description":"OK"
               },
               "400":{
                  "description":"Invalid Metadata",
                  "schema":{
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/MetadataResponse"
                  }
               },
               "404":{
                  "description":"Not found",
                  "schema":{
                     "type":"string"
                  }
               },
               "405":{
                  "description":"Method Not Allowed",
                  "schema":{
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/MetadataResponse"
                  }
               },
               "409":{
                  "description":"Conflict",
                  "schema":{
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/MetadataResponse"
                  }
               },
               "500":{
                  "description":"Internal Server Error"
               }
            }
         },
         "put":{
            "summary":"Metadata Update Individual",
            "description":"",
            "operationId":"updateIndividual",
            "consumes":[
               "application/json"
            ],
            "produces":[
               "application/json"
            ],
            "parameters":[
               {
                  "in":"body",
                  "name":"body",
                  "description":"metadata",
                  "required":true,
                  "schema":{
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/MetadataUpdate"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "responses":{
               "200":{
                  "description":"Request was processed"
               },
               "400":{
                  "description":"Bad Request, falls Validierung auf Request Objekt fehlschlägt"
               },
               "500":{
                  "description":"Interner Fehler"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "/metadata":{
         "post":{
            "summary":"\tMetadata Insert",
            "description":"",
            "operationId":"save",
            "consumes":[
               "application/json"
            ],
            "produces":[
               "application/json"
            ],
            "parameters":[
               {
                  "in":"body",
                  "name":"body",
                  "description":"metadata",
                  "required":true,
                  "schema":{
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/MetadataInsert"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "responses":{
               "200":{
                  "description":"OK"
               },
               "400":{
                  "description":"Invalid Metadata",
                  "schema":{
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/MetadataResponse"
                  }
               },
               "404":{
                  "description":"Not found",
                  "schema":{
                     "type":"string"
                  }
               },
               "405":{
                  "description":"Method Not Allowed",
                  "schema":{
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/MetadataResponse"
                  }
               },
               "409":{
                  "description":"Conflict",
                  "schema":{
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/MetadataResponse"
                  }
               },
               "500":{
                  "description":"Internal Server Error"
               }
            }
         },
         "put":{
            "summary":"Metadata Update",
            "description":"",
            "operationId":"update",
            "consumes":[
               "application/json"
            ],
            "produces":[
               "application/json"
            ],
            "parameters":[
               {
                  "in":"body",
                  "name":"body",
                  "description":"metadata",
                  "required":true,
                  "schema":{
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/MetadataUpdate"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "responses":{
               "200":{
                  "description":"Request was processed"
               },
               "400":{
                  "description":"Bad Request, falls Validierung auf Request Objekt fehlschlägt"
               },
               "500":{
                  "description":"Interner Fehler"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "definitions":{
      "MetadataKey":{
         "type":"object",
         "required":[
            "itemId"
         ],
         "properties":{
            "itemId":{
               "type":"string",
               "minLength":1,
               "maxLength":36
            },
            "itemCode":{
               "type":"string",
               "minLength":0,
               "maxLength":10
            }
         }
      },
      "MetadataResponse":{
         "type":"object",
         "required":[
            "itemId"
         ],
         "properties":{
            "itemId":{
               "type":"string",
               "minLength":1,
               "maxLength":36
            },
            "itemCode":{
               "type":"string",
               "minLength":0,
               "maxLength":10
            },
            "returnCode":{
               "type":"string",
               "enum":[
                  "OK",
                  "FAULT",
                  "IRRELEVANT",
                  "STATUS",
                  "TECHNICAL_ERROR"
               ]
            },
            "message":{
               "type":"string"
            }
         }
      },
      "MetadataUpdate":{
         "type":"object",
         "required":[
            "aType",
            "codeFrom",
            "iType",
            "isCodeRangeNumeric",
            "lengthOfCodes",
            "numberOfCodes",
            "oCategory",
            "itemId",
            "myExtraIds",
            "status",
            "targetCategory",
            "validDays",
            "validFrom",
            "validUntil"
         ],
         "properties":{
            "itemId":{
               "type":"string",
               "minLength":1,
               "maxLength":36
            },
            "itemCode":{
               "type":"string",
               "minLength":0,
               "maxLength":10
            },
            "uuid":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "validFrom":{
               "type":"string",
               "format":"date-time",
               "example":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
            },
            "validUntil":{
               "type":"string",
               "format":"date-time",
               "example":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
            },
            "validUntilOriginal":{
               "type":"string",
               "format":"date-time"
            },
            "validDays":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32"
            },
            "visibleFrom":{
               "type":"string",
               "format":"date-time",
               "example":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
            },
            "visibleTo":{
               "type":"string",
               "format":"date-time",
               "example":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
            },
            "aType":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"OFFLINE(1),ONLINE(2),BOTH(3)"
            },
            "multiRedeem":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "minimum":1,
               "maximum":2147483647
            },
            "targetCategory":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"desc"
            },
            "iType":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"desc"
            },
            "oCategory":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"desc"
            },
            "incentiveValueFrom":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32"
            },
            "incentiveValueTo":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32"
            },
            "externalID":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "couponID":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "codeFrom":{
               "type":"string",
               "minLength":1,
               "maxLength":2147483647
            },
            "codeTo":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "infoText":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "status":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"desc"
            },
            "numberOfCodes":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "minimum":1,
               "maximum":2147483647
            },
            "lengthOfCodes":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "minimum":4,
               "maximum":2147483647
            },
            "isCodeRangeNumeric":{
               "type":"boolean"
            },
            "interfaceOrigin":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"desc"
            },
            "myExtraIds":{
               "type":"array",
               "items":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "maxItems":2147483647,
               "minItems":1
            }
         }
      },
      "MetadataIndividualInsert":{
         "type":"object",
         "required":[
            "aType",
            "codeFrom",
            "iType",
            "isCodeRangeNumeric",
            "lengthOfCodes",
            "numberOfCodes",
            "oCategory",
            "itemId",
            "myExtraIds",
            "status",
            "targetCategory",
            "validDays",
            "validFrom",
            "validUntil"
         ],
         "properties":{
            "itemId":{
               "type":"string",
               "minLength":1,
               "maxLength":36
            },
            "itemCode":{
               "type":"string",
               "minLength":0,
               "maxLength":10
            },
            "uuid":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "validFrom":{
               "type":"string",
               "format":"date-time",
               "example":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
            },
            "validUntil":{
               "type":"string",
               "format":"date-time",
               "example":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
            },
            "validUntilOriginal":{
               "type":"string",
               "format":"date-time"
            },
            "validDays":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32"
            },
            "visibleFrom":{
               "type":"string",
               "format":"date-time",
               "example":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
            },
            "visibleTo":{
               "type":"string",
               "format":"date-time",
               "example":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
            },
            "aType":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"OFFLINE(1),ONLINE(2),BOTH(3)"
            },
            "multiRedeem":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "minimum":1,
               "maximum":2147483647
            },
            "targetCategory":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"desc"
            },
            "iType":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"desc"
            },
            "oCategory":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"desc"
            },
            "incentiveValueFrom":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32"
            },
            "incentiveValueTo":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32"
            },
            "externalID":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "couponID":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "codeFrom":{
               "type":"string",
               "minLength":1,
               "maxLength":2147483647
            },
            "codeTo":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "infoText":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "status":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"desc"
            },
            "numberOfCodes":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "minimum":1,
               "maximum":2147483647
            },
            "lengthOfCodes":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "minimum":4,
               "maximum":2147483647
            },
            "isCodeRangeNumeric":{
               "type":"boolean"
            },
            "interfaceOrigin":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"desc"
            },
            "myExtraIds":{
               "type":"array",
               "items":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "maxItems":2147483647,
               "minItems":1
            }
         }
      },
      "MetadataInsert":{
         "type":"object",
         "required":[
            "aType",
            "codeFrom",
            "iType",
            "isCodeRangeNumeric",
            "lengthOfCodes",
            "numberOfCodes",
            "oCategory",
            "itemId",
            "myExtraIds",
            "status",
            "targetCategory",
            "validDays",
            "validFrom",
            "validUntil"
         ],
         "properties":{
            "itemId":{
               "type":"string",
               "minLength":1,
               "maxLength":36
            },
            "itemCode":{
               "type":"string",
               "minLength":0,
               "maxLength":10
            },
            "uuid":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "validFrom":{
               "type":"string",
               "format":"date-time",
               "example":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
            },
            "validUntil":{
               "type":"string",
               "format":"date-time",
               "example":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
            },
            "validUntilOriginal":{
               "type":"string",
               "format":"date-time"
            },
            "validDays":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32"
            },
            "visibleFrom":{
               "type":"string",
               "format":"date-time",
               "example":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
            },
            "visibleTo":{
               "type":"string",
               "format":"date-time",
               "example":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
            },
            "aType":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"OFFLINE(1),ONLINE(2),BOTH(3)"
            },
            "multiRedeem":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "minimum":1,
               "maximum":2147483647
            },
            "targetCategory":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"desc"
            },
            "iType":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"desc"
            },
            "oCategory":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"desc"
            },
            "incentiveValueFrom":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32"
            },
            "incentiveValueTo":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32"
            },
            "externalID":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "couponID":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "codeFrom":{
               "type":"string",
               "minLength":1,
               "maxLength":2147483647
            },
            "codeTo":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "infoText":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "status":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"desc"
            },
            "numberOfCodes":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "minimum":1,
               "maximum":2147483647
            },
            "lengthOfCodes":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "minimum":4,
               "maximum":2147483647
            },
            "isCodeRangeNumeric":{
               "type":"boolean"
            },
            "interfaceOrigin":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int32",
               "description":"desc"
            },
            "myExtraIds":{
               "type":"array",
               "items":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "maxItems":2147483647,
               "minItems":1
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Does anybody can give my a hint what to do or where to look at?

Comment: 1) Can you post your JSON definition? 2) If you use HTTP version of the editor, try the HTTPS version - https://editor.swagger.io.

Comment: Hi @helen, I have updated the question and inserted the JSON context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by a very large `maxItems` value in array definitions in the spec:

```
"maxItems":2147483647
```

It causes an out-of-memory error in Swagger Codegen, see [this issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/6394) for details.

The workaround is to remove `maxItems` from your spec.

Comment: That's it :-)
Many thanks to you Helen, you saved my day.